# Error NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript

Please note that other questions about the same error didn't help because I'm using different way to get the data.

I want to get some data from the API and show them in the page using `Angular`.
The http request will get an array of projects.
so here is the `projects.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Project {

    alias:Array<string>;
    apps:Array<string>;
    description: string;
    id:string;
    name:string;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})


export class ProjectsComponent {



    title:string = "Projects";
    dataProjects: Array<Project>;

    constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient){  }

    getProjects() {
    this.httpClient.get<Array<Project>>("http://company.com/v1/api/projects")
    .subscribe(  data  => { this.dataProjects = data; } )
  }

}
```

and here is the view in projects.component.html:

```
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let proj of dataProjects">
      <td> {{ proj.name }}  </td>
      <td>{{ proj.description }}  </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

This is the error I get:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

How to return an array of Projects ?

EDIT:

Example of output of the API:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alias": [
        "project"
      ], 
      "apps": [], 
      "description": "Applications natives", 
      "id": "project", 
      "name": "project"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: When I use | keyvalue I get empty data

Comment: try data.json()

Comment: Where to put data.json() ?

Comment: What is the output of `http://company.com/v1/api/projects` ?

Comment: check the update please. thank you

Comment: subscribe(  data  => { this.dataProjects = data.json(); } )

Comment: When I use data.json() I get: `ERROR TypeError: "data.json is not a function"`

Comment: `let proj of dataProjects.results` worked !!! thank you

Comment: @Somar , Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method `getProjects` is never called. That means `dataProjects` is `null`

Try

```
<tr *ngFor="let proj of dataProjects?.results">
      <td> {{ proj.name }}  </td>
      <td>{{ proj.description }}  </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason why you get this problem is because the variable hasn't been assigned yet when angular tries to iterate through it, so it doesn't have a javascript type yet. You should instead save the observable and use the async pipe in the html-template.

in the typescript:

```
dataProjects$: Observable<Array<Project>>

getProjects() {
    this.dataProjects$ = this.httpClient.get<Array<Project>>("http://company.com/v1/api/projects")
}
```

in the html:

```
<div *ngIf="dataProjects$ | async as dataProjects">
  <tr *ngFor="let proj of dataProjects">
    <td> {{ proj.name }}  </td>
    <td>{{ proj.description }}  </td>
  </tr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
<tr *ngFor="let proj of dataProjects.results ">
  <td> {{ proj.name }}  </td>
  <td>{{ proj.description }}  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: look at my answer. better to check null in dataProjects

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

**DO NOT USE** `*ngFor="let proj of dataProjects?.results"`

**Reason :** You already have defined the type of `dataProjects` as  `Array<Project>`

So doing `this.dataProjects = data;`violates the type , instead of that use `this.dataProjects = data. results;`

---

**All you need to do is**

```
getProjects() {
    this.httpClient.get<Array<Project>>("http://company.com/v1/api/projects")
    .subscribe(  data  => { this.dataProjects = data.results; } ) // <--- Change here
}
```

No need to change anything on `template` side.